# Upgrading symfony sonata to 3.x

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

i upgraded symfony-sonata to 3.x and getting error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException: The target-entity Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Category cannot be found in 'App\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media#category'. in /vagrant/src/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/MappingException.php on line 762
```

Which. I don't know how to resolve. Any Ideas?
in sonata 2.x everything worked

Why error pointing to Application\ instead of App\ ?

Answer (score 1):

The classification bundle has been made optional recently. Just reinstall it ;)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll try to reinstall it

Comment: Your answer did not help me. 
I'm still getting same error

Comment: @Dev-stud `composer require sonata-project/classification-bundle`

Comment: @JulesLamur I have it latest installed. But error still same.

Comment: Problem is, that my defoult location is app. And error pointing to Application

Comment: > Why error pointing to Application\ instead of App\ ? 
I don't think it's an error… in my application, it's `src/Application`.

Comment: and in mine is
`src/App`

Comment: The docs talk about `Application` though, not `App` : https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/2-x/doc/reference/why.html Either it is supposed to be configurable and then it means `Application` is wrongly harcoded somewhere, or you should rename your directory